# How to manipulate the excel data in SqlBulkCopy?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am importing excel sheet into sql server db table, for eg:
id | Data(which is date)
the format of date in excel is mm/dd/yyyy i want it to get stored in database as yyyy/mm/dd i have no idea how to do it the following is my code to upload the excel:

```
   using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
                {
                   bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "ExcelTable";
                   bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);

               }
                dr.Close();
```

and i found a code to convert date but i dont know how to integrate this code with the above:

```
    string a = "12/20/2012";
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(a);
    string st = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Label1.Text = a;
    Label2.Text = st;
```

Comment: Basically, the job of `SqlBulkCopy` is to load data as quickly as possible. It's not intended to be a data manipulation engine, too. If you need to load data and **transform it** at the same time, use the SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) which offer all sorts of ways to manipulate and tweak your data

Answer (score 0):

Did this a good couple of years back but the idea is as follows:

It appears as though you are inserting from a `DataReader`.  If you use your own `DataTable` you could place the data in *there* in the format you choose and then write the `DataTable` to the server:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x.aspx

Comment: alright i use dt.Load(dr) 
now how can i convert the data column the way i want

Comment: If you want to use `dt.Load(dr)` you would need to iterate over the table and transform the relevant data.  Another alternative is to load the data in row-by-row into the `DataTable` but the load and iteration may be quicker.

Comment: i am a complete newbie can you explain how i can iterate row by row in this case

Comment: `foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows) { row[3].Value = *transform*; }` --- where 3 is the relevant column.  Didn't check this but that is the idea :)

Comment: red line on Value:
the object does not contain definition for 'Value' accepting a first  argument of type object could not be found are you missing a namespace or directive

Comment: OK, checked: drop the `.Value`.  So `row[*column_number*] = *transform*;`